# sharepoint online api error authenticating

Tags: python, api, sharepoint

getting this error trying to authenticate sharepoint online:

context_auth = AuthenticationContext(url=app_settings['url'])
TypeError: AuthenticationContext.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'url'

Process finished with exit code 1

[image with code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24Tc8.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code as Text and not as an image.  Also include the full traceback error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I gathered from your error, `AuthenticationContext()`
doesn't have a `url` parameter.

From the code:

https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/blob/master/office365/runtime/auth/authentication_context.py

it looks like the parameter is actually `authority_url`.

So:

```
context_auth = AuthenticationContext(url=app_settings['url'])
```

should really be:

```
context_auth = AuthenticationContext(app_settings['url'])
```

Assuming the app_settings['url'] is the correct authority url.